# Has the ViewingApplication constructor been removed from the AD Viewer API?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

After leaving my Autodesk extension alone for a few weeks, my initialization code is failing to create a ViewingApplication.

In my browser's js console, I can see that the Autodesk.Viewing object contains many objects, but it no longer contains any ViewingApplication.
The [Viewer API documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewingapplication/) still includes ViewingApplication.

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
    viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
    var config3d = {
      extensions: ['WharfExtension']
    };
    viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config3d);
    var model = 'urn:' + defaultModel;
    viewerApp.loadDocument(model, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
});
```

My browser says, "Uncaught TypeError: Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication is not a constructor," and I am inclined to agree?

EDIT: It works as expected from my coworker's machine, so apparently it is not a problem with the API. I am serving the page from a web server on my machine.

EDIT2: Solved. Thanks, Petr. I was including the new, non-backwards-compatible version of the API without realizing it.
Autodesk describes how to create this behavior in the new version in their [Migration Guide v6 to v7](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The viewer team has recently released [new major version](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-autodesk-forge-viewer-70-now-available) which is not backwards compatible.

Make sure that you're importing the *viewer3d.js*/*viewer3d.min.js* file with the expected major version. For example, if you've built your application against version 6 APIs, you should be using the following script tag:

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```